# Example of category in which direct limit does not exist

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I am trying to understand concept of direct limit.I am looking for

> An example of a category and directed sequence whose direct limit does not exist.

I am unable to find one please help.

Comment: Hint: pick a small category. Like, really small. Alternatively, take any category and directed sequence that *does* have a direct limit, and break the universality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** In a posetal category, a direct limit of a chain $x_0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots$ (considered as a directed diagram $x_0 \to x_1 \to x_2 \to \cdots$ of morphisms in the category) is exactly a supremum of the chain.

Comment: Can you expand bit more? I don’t know about posetal category.

Comment: @MathLover: Every (preorder or) poset $(X, \le)$ defines a category $\mathbb{X}$, where the objects of $\mathbb{X}$ are the elements of $X$, and where there exists (exactly) one morphism $x \to y$ if and only if $x \le y$. The uniqueness of morphisms makes it easy to check that the colimit of a chain $x_0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots$ is a supremum of the chain.

Comment: Thanks. Probably it’s easy but I can’t see why the supremum is direct limit. Can you please explain?

Comment: @MathLover: Here's the gist. A direct limit $a$ in particular comes equipped with morphisms $x_n \to a$ for each $n \ge 0$, which is to say that $a$ is an upper bound for the chain. The universal property tells you that $a$ is a *least* upper bound: if there are morphisms $x_n \to b$ for some other $b \in X$, then the morphism $a \to b$ coming from the universal property tells you that $a \le b$.

Answer (score 1):

[An initial object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/terminal+object) in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a direct limit (to be more precise, it is the direct limit of the unique functor $\emptyset\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, where $\emptyset$ is the [empty category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+category)), so to find an example for your question it suffices to find a category without initial object.

The first one that comes to my mind is $\mathbf{Fld}$, the category of fields. To see that this category does not have a initial object, just ask yourself what should be the characteristic of an eventual "initial field".  In general, I think that it is nice and useful to try to figure out what kinds of limits and colimits are admitted in $\mathbf{Fld}$.